# What's wrong with this Codility Answer?

Tags: javascript

The question was to find the largest binary gap in a number, and while this worked in my IDE, Codility didn't accept it. Any thoughts?

```js
const biGap = (number) => {
  const binary = number.toString(2)
  const re = /1(0+)1/g;
  const found = binary.match(re)
  let counter = 0
  found.map((match) => {
    if (match.length > counter) {
      counter = match.length
    }
  })
  return (counter - 2);
}

console.log(biGap(1041));
```

Comment: Can you define "binary gap"? Does it only apply to `1`s here?

Comment: It doesn't look correct to me. The regexp doesn't find overlapping matches, so if the input is `10010000010001` it will return `1001` and `10001`, but not `1000001`, which contains the longest gap.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Based on his code, it seems like it's a series of 0 bits between 1 bits in the binary representation of a number.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but they got the answer incorrect :) So I was curious if the real problem statement could be included.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen he got the answer incorrect because he has a bug in the program, as I stated.

Comment: @Barmar That is a guess since we don't know the _actual_ acceptance criteria of the problem. (It is probably right, but still a guess)

Comment: Does a binary gap include zeroes at the end of the number, e.g. `10100000` does that have a gap of 1 or 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that `binary.match(re)` won't return overlapping matches. So if `binary = "1010000001001"`, it will return `["101", "1001"]`, which is missing the long gap `10000001` between them.

You can solve this by changing the regexp to

```
const re = /0+1/g;
```

Then you should return `counter - 1` instead of `counter - 2`.

You don't need to put `1` on both sides of the `0+` because `number.toString(2)` will never include leading zeroes, so there's always a `1` to the left of any string of zeroes, and it's not necessary to match it explicitly.

If you also want to include the binary gap in the low order bits of the number, you can change the regexp to simply:

```
const re = /0+/g;
```

Then you don't need to subtract anything from `counter` when returning.

```js
const biGap = (number) => {
  const binary = number.toString(2)
  const re = /0+1/g;
  const found = binary.match(re)
  let counter = 0
  found.map((match) => {
    if (match.length > counter) {
      counter = match.length
    }
  })
  return (counter - 1);
}

console.log(biGap(1041));
console.log(biGap(parseInt("1010000001001", 2))); // Your code returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function binGap(N) {
    var max=0;
    var count=0;
    var binary = Number(N).toString(2);;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(binary,function(i) {
       if(i == 0) {
           count++;
       } else {
           if(count > max) {
               max = count;
           }
           count = 0;
       }
    });
    return max;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really attempt to answer the question, which is "what's wrong with the given code"

Answer (score 0):

for starters make sure that the regex returns all the right candidates

map operator is used the wrong way. Reduce is the way to use in your case

you should not subtract 2 from the counter at return, instead do that in the reduce callback

don't console.log

And a final thought, why convert the number into string? why not use modulo 2? it's way simpler and efficient. (think of how much resources a regex requires)

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution may be this

```js
solution(N) {
    while(N && N%2 === 0) {
        N = N>>1
    }
    
    let counter = 0;
    let tempCounter = 0;
    let n=N;
    
    while(n) {
        if(n%2 === 1) {
            counter = Math.max(counter, tempCounter);
            tempCounter=0;
        } else {
            tempCounter = tempCounter + 1;
        }
        n = n>>1;
    }
    
    return counter;
    
}
```